# Подгрузка из Firebase Firestore в recycle view

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, firebase

Загружаю данные из Firebase Firestore в recycle view и пытаюсь сделать постепенную подгрузку данных при достижении конца списка.

Вроде бы получилось, но работает не совсем корректно:

1) при переходе на другой фрагмент и возвращении обратно на этот, отображаются не все записи и подгрузка не работает

2) при попытке обновить список с помощью swipeRefreshLayout он обновляется, но показываются только последние 4 записи, подгрузка также перестает работать

3) переодически при прокрутке (например, когда записей меньше чем сам лимит) может вылетать с ошибкой в 194 строке `lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);` пишет length=0; index=-1

Как решить эти проблемы? Помогите, пожалуйста

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private final int LIMIT_ITEM_LOAD = 4;

    private View item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
    private boolean isScrolling;
    private boolean isLastItemReached;
    private List<Meeting> list;
    private MeetingAdapter adapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        item_1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_1);
        item_2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_2);
        item_3 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_3);
        item_4 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_4);
        item_5 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_5);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        setBorderItemSelected(item_1);

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("Лента событий");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        swipeRefresh = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(
                R.color.orange_300,
                R.color.pink_300,
                R.color.green_300,
                R.color.blue_300);
        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);

        getLastKeyFromFirebase();

        return view;
    }



    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener refreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
                    getLastKeyFromFirebase();
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            },1000);
        }
    };



    private void getLastKeyFromFirebase() {

        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("meetings")
                .orderBy("id", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(LIMIT_ITEM_LOAD);

        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Meeting meeting = document.toObject(Meeting.class);
                        list.add(meeting);
                    }

                    adapter = new MeetingAdapter(list, getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Основа загружена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

                }
            }
        });
    }



    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            Log.d("Ok","firstVisibleItem = " + firstVisibleItem);
            Log.d("Ok","visibleItemCount = " + visibleItemCount);
            Log.d("Ok","totalItemCount = " + totalItemCount);

            if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                isScrolling = false;

                Query nextQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("meetings")
                        .orderBy("id", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                        .startAfter(lastVisible)
                        .limit(LIMIT_ITEM_LOAD);
                nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Meeting meeting = document.toObject(Meeting.class);
                            list.add(meeting);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Подгрузка завершена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if (task.getResult().size() < LIMIT_ITEM_LOAD) {
                            isLastItemReached = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    };




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_filtration:
                //
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_home, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

}
```

MeetingAdapter.java

```
public class MeetingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MeetingAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Meeting> meetingsList;
    private Context context;

    public MeetingAdapter(List<Meeting> meetingsList, Context context) {
        this.meetingsList = meetingsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MeetingAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_meeting, parent, false);
        return new MeetingAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MeetingAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.date.setText(meetingsList.get(position).getDate());
        holder.title.setText(meetingsList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return meetingsList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView date, title;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Это не касательно ответа, почему вы используйте item_1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.item_1);, если можно к view.find........ сделать?

Comment: @danilshik эти view находятся вне фрагмента, на самом активити

Comment: типо FrameLayout внутри другого блока?

Comment: @danilshik да в другом